# json file error: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json, currency, discord.py

I'm using discord.py to create a multipurpose discord bot, but I have been having some trouble making custom currency.

I decided on using a .json file to store the names and currency of everyone on the server, but I'm getting this error when I run this:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands
import random
from discord import Game
import discord
import json
load_dotenv()
TOKEN = 'TOKENHERE'
GUILD = os.getenv('DISCORD_GUILD')  # Same thing but gets the server name
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='r!')
on = "I'm up and running!"
print("Booting up...")
cmds = ["r!test - responds with: I hear you!"]
channel2 = bot.get_channel(CHANNELID)

@bot.event  # idk what this means but you have to do it
async def on_ready():  # when the bot is ready
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        if guild.name == GUILD:
            break
    print(
        f'{bot.user} has connected to Discord! They have connected to the following server: '  # client.user is just the bot name
        f'{guild.name}(id: {guild.id})')  # guild.name is just the server name
    channel2 = bot.get_channel(703869904264101969)
    global amounts
    try:
        with open('amounts.json') as f:
            amounts = json.load(f)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Could not load amounts.json")
        amounts = {}
    await channel2.send(on)
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="r!help"))


@bot.command(name='test', help='Responds with: I can hear you! Used mainly for testing. ')
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("I hear you!")

@bot.command(name='ping', help='Tells you the latency of the bot.')
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Pong! " + str(int(bot.latency) * 1000) + "ms!")

@bot.command(name='say or simonsays', help='Responds with whatever you say after.', aliases = ['say', 'simonsays'])
async def say(ctx, *, contents: str):
   await ctx.send(contents)

@bot.command(name='diceroll', help='Rolls a dice!')
async def diceroll(ctx, number_of_dice: int, number_of_sides: int):
    dice = [
        str(random.choice(range(1, number_of_sides + 1)))
        for i in range(number_of_dice)
    ]
    await ctx.send(', '.join(dice))

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await channel2.send(f'{member} has joined the server.')

@bot.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    await channel2.send(f'{member} has left the server. F')

@bot.command(name='coolnotcool', help='Tells you whether you are cool or not.')
async def coolnotcool(ctx, *, member: str):
    coolornot = random.choice(range(1, 3))
    if coolornot == 1:
        await ctx.send(f'{member} is cool.')
    elif coolornot == 2:
        await ctx.send(f'{member} is not cool.')

@bot.command(name='8ball', help='Ask it a question and it will respond')
async def eightball(ctx, question):
    answers=['It is certain.', 'Without a doubt.', 'You may rely on it.', 'Yes, definitely.', 'It is decidedly so.', 'As I see it, yes.', 'Most likely.', 'Yes.', 'Outlook good.', 'Signs point to yes.', 'Reply hazy, try again.', 'Better not tell you now.', 'Ask again later.', 'Cannot predict now.', 'Concentrate, then ask again.', 'Dont count on it.', 'Outlook not so good.', 'My sources say no.', 'Very doubtful.', 'My reply is no.']
    response = random.choice(range(1, 21))
    await ctx.send(str(answers[response]))

@bot.command(name='coinflip', help='Responds with either heads or tails. Good for making a decision.')
async def coinflip(ctx):
    answer = random.choice(range(1, 3))
    if answer == 1:
        await ctx.send('Heads!')
    else:
        await ctx.send('Tails!')

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send('Please pass in all required arguments.')
bot.run(TOKEN)

@bot.command(pass_context=True, name='bal', help='Shows you how many rb you have in the bank.')
async def bal(ctx):
    id = str(ctx.message.author.id)
    if id in amounts:
        await ctx.send("You have {} in the rb bank".format(amounts[id]))
    else:
        await ctx.send("You do not have an account yet. Type r!register to register!")

@bot.command(pass_context=True, name='register', help='Register to start using RuinBot currency!')
async def register(ctx):
    id = str(ctx.message.author.id)
    if id not in amounts:
        amounts[id] = 100
        await ctx.send("You are now registered! Remember, type r!save to save!")
        _save()
    else:
        await ctx.send("You already have an account.")

@bot.command(name='save', help='Your currency autosaves, but remember to always save just in case! This saves your currency.')
async def save(ctx):
    _save()
    await ctx.send("Data saved!")

@bot.command(pass_context=True, name='give', help='Give another member some rb!')
async def give(ctx, amount: int, other: discord.Member):
    primary_id = str(ctx.message.author.id)
    other_id = str(other.id)
    if primary_id not in amounts:
        await ctx.send("You do not have an account")
    elif other_id not in amounts:
        await ctx.send("The other party does not have an account")
    elif amounts[primary_id] < amount:
        await ctx.send("You cannot afford this transaction")
    else:
        amounts[primary_id] -= amount
        amounts[other_id] += amount
        await ctx.send("Transaction complete")
    _save()

def _save():
    with open('amounts.json', 'w+') as f:
        json.dump(amounts, f)
```

If anyone could help with this, that would be great. The .json file is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The empty json file is your error. Edit the json file so that it contains the following: 
`{}`